# PAM configuration to execute a shell script on every login failure

Tags: shell-script, authentication, pam

I would like to execute my shell script on every login failure. To do this I updated the file `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`: From (original body):

```
auth    required    pam_env.so
auth    required    pam_unix2.so
```

to:

```
auth    required    pam_env.so
auth    sufficient  pam_unix2.so
auth    optional    pam_exec.so seteuid /root/handle_failure.sh
```

For most PAM services (like ssh, active directory) it works, but the problem is with login service. If I type the wrong password the script is executed but also the login is successful. I suspect that the result of `pam_unix2` module is ignored because of changing the flag from required to sufficient.

To fix it, I decided to change the PAM config to the new one: the new body of `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth    required    pam_env.so
auth    [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=ok ignore=ignore default=bad]  pam_unix2.so
auth    optional    pam_exec.so /root/handle_failure.sh
auth    optional    pam_exec.so /bin/true
```

This work as expected, but I don't like the last line `auth optional pam_exec.so /bin/true`. Without that line, the login doesn’t work because in line with `success=1`, we want to skip one line and we jump to nothing. Is there a better way to improve that configuration?